# Perform LINQ in Entity Framework core to load sub-related entities Data

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on .NET Core application with Entity Framework Core. I have three tables Questions, Answer and AnswerType 
so schema is as

```
question <-- 1:* --> Answers <-- 1:1--> AnswerTypes
```

I need to run query that return questions with ICollection of Answer , further Answer with AnswerType

### Question

```
public class QuestionDataModel
{
    public QuestionDataModel()
    {
        Answers = new HashSet<AnswerDataModel>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AnswerDataModel> Answers { get; set; }

}
```

### Answer

```
public class AnswerDataModel
{
    public AnswerDataModel()
    {
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionDataModel Question { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Guid AnswerStatusTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual AnswerStatusTypeDataModel AnswerStatusType { get; set; }

}
```

### AnswerStatusType

```
public class AnswerStatusTypeDataModel
{
    public AnswerStatusTypeDataModel()
    {
        Answers = new HashSet<AnswerDataModel>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AnswerDataModel> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried nested join to get AnswerStatusType of each answer in collection but getting error "invalid anonymous type member declared, anonymous type member must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access". This error appears in 2nd nested join in following code,

### linq

```
 var query3 = Context.Questions.Join(Context.Answers,
                       question => question.Id,
                       answer => answer.QuestionId,
                       (question, answer) => new
                       {
                           question.Id,
                           question.Title,
                           question.Answers.Join(Context.AnswerStatusTypes,
                                                  answer => answer.AnswerStatusTypeId,
                                                  answerStatus => answerStatus.Id,
                                                  (answers, answerStatus) => new
                                                  {
                                                      answerStatus
                                                  })
                       }
                     );
```

### Configuration Classes

```
 and configuration classes as
```

### Question Config

```
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<QuestionDataModel> builder)
    {

        builder.ToTable("Questions");
        builder.HasKey(question => question.Id);
        builder.HasMany(question => question.Answers);
    }
```

### Answer Config

```
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AnswerDataModel> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Answers");
        builder.HasKey(answer => answer.Id);

        builder
            .HasOne(answer => answer.Question)
            .WithMany(question => question.Answers)
            .HasForeignKey(answer => answer.QuestionId);

        builder
            .HasOne(answer => answer.AnswerStatusType)
            .WithMany(answerType => answerType.Answers)
            .HasForeignKey(answer => answer.AnswerStatusTypeId);
    }
```

### AnswerStatus COnfig

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AnswerStatusTypeDataModel> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("AnswerStatusTypes");
        builder.HasKey(answerStatusType => answerStatusType.Id);
        builder.HasMany(answerStatusType => answerStatusType.Answers);
    }
```

Comment: When googling for the exception, didn't you get *any* hints?

Answer (score 2):

Your entity configurations look correct to me.

As @Ivan Stoev pointed out,

```
var questions = context.Questions
    .Include(x => x.Answers)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.AnswerStatusType)
    // Now since we have the AnswerStatusType loaded we can do something like this as well.
    //.Where(x => x.Answers.Conatins(a => a.AnswerStatusType.Name == "Some Status Name"))
    .ToList();
```

This should do!

Comment: I cannot find object reference of AnswerStatusType in  .ThenInclude(x => x.AnswerStatusType)

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean? Do you mean the IntelliSense?

Comment: I am looking another way too considering entity framework core has some bugs

Comment: Right, I have seen the issue where IntelliSense doesn't complete ThenInclude. If you find any bugs with EF Core, please let the team know by opening up an issue here, https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues

Comment: @toxic You should try the suggested code as is. There is a known Intellisense issue, but it's irrelevant to whether this code compiles/works or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Context.Questions
             .Include(x=>x.Answers.Select(y=>y.AnswerType))
             .Where(x=>x.ID == QuestionidYouAreLookingFor)
             .ToList();
```

make sure include `System.Data.Entity` namespace

When you call ToList() its actually going to make SQL call and execute the query. If you want lazy loading then don't call ToList()

Comment: I am getting following error System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property expression 'question => {from AnswerDataModel y in question.Answers select [y].AnswerStatusType}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'

Comment: I cannot find namespace System.Data.Entity, is it part of EF Core?

Comment: I believe there is bug in EF Core hence cannot find reference of above approach

Comment: need another way to achieve this

Comment: EF-core syntax is `Include-ThenInclude`.

Comment: This answer is for EF6 and is not applicable for EF Core. @toxic Not sure what you have tried, but if your model is configured properly, `Questions.Include(x => x.Answers).ThenInclude(x => x.AnswerStatusType)` will load the desired information. In LINQ to Entities we don't (or very rarely) use explicit joins.

Comment: I have added config classes above in my question if you see any obvious mistake, please do let me know